# Can Father component show child component state ??

Tags: reactjs, redux

**DragAndResizeBox.js**

I use `ref={(c) => { this.resizableandmovable = c; }}`  in `ResizableAndMovable` as the `react-rnd` document said
I found I can get `this.resizableandmovable.state.x` ,`this.resizableandmovable.state.y`

```
class DragAndResizeBox extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onDragStop = (event, ui) => {
    console.log("[onDragStop]state:",this.resizableandmovable.state)
  }

  render() {
    const { canDrop, isOver, connectDropTarget } = this.props;
    const isActive = canDrop && isOver;
    const { contentObjectId, boxType } = this.props

    return connectDropTarget(
      <div>
        <ResizableAndMovable
          ref={(c) => { this.resizableandmovable = c; }}
          initial = {{
            x:this.props.axisX ? this.props.axisX: 0,
            y:this.props.axisY ? this.props.axisY :0,
            width:this.props.width ? this.props.width: 200,
            height:this.props.height ? this.props.height: 200,
          }}
          onDragStop={this.onDragStop}
        >
          <div className={this.getCssStyle(boxType)}>
            {this.show(contentObjectId)}

          </div>
        </ResizableAndMovable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

But I want to show the position x,y 
How can I get the `this.resizableandmovable.state` in father component ?

**father component **

```
import DragAndResizeBox from './DragAndResizeBox';
boxes.map(box => {
  return (
      <DragAndResizeBox key={box.id} />
  );
});

// Can I directly access  this.resizableandmovable.state ???  
//<div>X:<textarea>{this.resizableandmovable.state.x}</textarea>Y:{this.resizableandmovable.state.y}<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no you can't.

What you can and should do is to store state in the parent component. And pass down to child component via props.
Updating function also normally sits inside parent component and passed down as props to the child.